# Composer require local PHAR file

Tags: dependencies, composer-php, phar

I build a small PHP library as a PHAR file. It is not published anywhere, I just have it like PHAR file locally. Lets say its name is '**myLib.phar**'

I want to test and use this library in another project, '**myProject**'

How can I require '**myLib.phar**' in 'composer.json', in order to get the phar copied in the project's vendor directory?

Here is myProject's composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "myProject",
    "description": "myProject Description.",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1",
        "myLib": "@dev"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../../../path/to/myLib.phar"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I add a dependency to '**myLib.phar**'  with composer?